# JOIN NOT DISPLAYING ALL RECORDS

Tags: sql

I'm sure that this is pretty obvious but I am completely stuck as I have never seen this before.

I have a data set that can vary against a list of categories (6 in total). Some clients will have 1 or 2 categories other all 6. The information I'm trying to pull through is designed to pull through all 6 categories with the corresponding information depending on the client.

So I have set up a simple mapping table with ID (1 to 6) and Category. I'm then joining this to my client data. The test data I'm using has categories 1,2,3,5 and whilst I get a NULL of 6 I get nothing for 4. I should see a Null row on category 4 as it doesn't exist in the client data?

```
 SELECT *

FROM .dbo.Lookup_Category C

LEFT JOIN dbo.Client CL ON C.ID = CL.Category

WHERE CL.ID = 423 OR CL.Category IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you show the raw data and table schema?

Comment: Did you tried: left outer join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
 SELECT *
 FROM .dbo.Lookup_Category C
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Client CL ON C.ID = CL.Category and ( CL.ID = 423 OR CL.Category IS NULL )
```

the use of where in left join is used as an inner join

Answer (score 2):

Move your `WHERE` condition to your `ON` clause.

The `WHERE` executes *after* the `LEFT JOIN` and will filter out your `NULL` values for `CL.ID`.

```
SELECT *
FROM .dbo.Lookup_Category C
LEFT JOIN dbo.Client CL ON C.ID = CL.Category
                        AND (CL.ID = 423 OR CL.Category IS NULL)
```

Comment: Am i right that when you make it an left outer join, that you can then use the where clause?

Comment: @Svenmarim A `LEFT JOIN` is the same thing as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  The `OUTER` keyword is completely optional.